# Call to a member function setAttributes() on a non-object yii2

Tags: yii2, setattribute

It says that I have error here  but I cant figure out how to fix it : 
[image]

here is my _form  - http://pastebin.com/HjMZ33Hj

and my Controller - http://pastebin.com/7ZfD6hqq

P.S. sorry that I use pastebin ,but cant copy the code here and to look good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code on line 130 fails to find a model with `id` that you have in `where` condition, thus returns `null` instead of `Dependency` object.

You should introduce a bit more logic to check, whether `Dependency::find()->...->one()` returned a model or `null`.

Comment: done it with  : 
if (array_key_exists('dependentId', $dComp) && isset($dComp['dependentId'])) {
                    $dependencyModel = Dependency::find()->where(['id' => $dComp['dependentId']])->one();
                if (!$dependencyModel) {
                        $dependencyModel = new Dependency();
                    }
                } else {
                    $dependencyModel = new Dependency();
                }

Comment: Great! Then could you mark this answer as correct? ;)